# Vim's omnicompletion fails with "from" imports in Python

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete, import

Omnicompletion for Python seems to fail when there is a "from" import instead of a normal one.
For example, if I have these two files:

Test.py:

```
class Test:
    def method(self):
        pass
```

main.py:

```
from Test import Test

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = Test()
```

If I try to activate omnicompletion for self.x... it says "Pattern not found".
However, if I change the import statement to:

```
import Test
```

and the self.x declaration to:

```
self.x = Test.Test()
```

then I'm able to use omnicompletion as expected (it suggests "method", for example).

I'm using Vim 7.2.245 and the default plugin for Python code completion (pythoncomplete).
Should I set some variable? Or is this behavior expected?

**Update**:

Based on Jared's answer, I found out something by accident:

Omnicompletion doesn't work on this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = StringIO()
        self.x.<C-x><C-o>

s = Test()
```

But works on this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = StringIO()
        self.x.<C-x><C-o>

s = Test()
s.x = StringIO()
```

The only difference is the redeclaration of x (actually, it also works if I remove the declaration inside `__init__`).

I tested my example again, and I think the problem is not the "from" import, but the use of the imported class inside another class.
If I change the file `main.py` to:

```
from Test import Test

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = Test()
       self.x.<C-x><C-o>

y = Test()
y.<C-x><C-o>
```

The first attempt to use omnicompletion fails, but the second works fine.
So yep, looks like a bug in the plugin :)

Comment: What all this amounts to is: no, it's not expected, and you're not doing anything wrong =) it's a bug. Looks like the script is maintained here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542 I suggest filing a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

**update:** ooh, so I checked your example, and I get completion for

```
x = Test()
x.<C-x><C-o>
```

but not

```
o = object()
o.x = Test()
o.x.<C-x><C-o>
```

...I'm gonna do some digging

**update 2:** *revenge of Dr. Strangelove*

and...this is where it get's weird.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
class M:
    pass
s = M()
s.x = StringIO()
s.x.<C-x><C-o>
```

completes. but this

```
from StringIO import StringIO
class M: pass
s = M()
s.x = StringIO()
s.x.<C-x><C-o>
```

Did you catch the difference? *nothing syntactically -- just a little whitespace*

And yet it breaks completion. So there's definitely a parsing bug in there somewhere (*why* they don't just use the `ast` module, I have no idea...)

*[end of updates]*

On first blush, I can't reproduce your problem; here's my test file:

```
from os import path
path.<C-x><C-o>
```

and I get completion. Now, I know it's not exactly your situation, but it shows that pythoncomplete knows about 'from'.

And now the more in-depth example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
s = StringIO()
s.<C-x><C-o>
```

And...completion! Could you try that example to **see if it works with builtin modules for you?** If that's the case, you should probably check paths...

If it still doesnt work, and you're up for some digging around, check out line #555 of pythoncomplete.vim [at `/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim` on my ubuntu machine]:

```
            elif token == 'from':                                    
                mod, token = self._parsedotname()                    
                if not mod or token != "import":                     
                    print "from: syntax error..."                    
                    continue                                         
                names = self._parseimportlist()                      
                for name, alias in names:                            
                    loc = "from %s import %s" % (mod,name)           
                    if len(alias) > 0: loc += " as %s" % alias       
                    self.scope.local(loc)                            
                freshscope = False
```

as you can see, this is where it handles `from` statements.

Cheers